# changing an href using javascript in a class containing matching classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration, href

so I have this html code with jquery imported

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-12  no_padding" id="vdp_buttons">
    <a href="/quote/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-2">
    Request Something     
    </a><br>
    <a href="/test_drive/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-2">
    Test Something   
    </a><br>
    <a href="/availability/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    Check Something 
    </a><br>
    <a href="/appraisal/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    Trade Something 
    </a><br>
</div>
<script>

//Something goes here

</script>
```

I want to use jquery to change one of those links, but all the classes are the same. The only thing I can reference is the id "vdp_buttons". Is there a way using jquery or javascript to iterate through each link and change a specific href in this case, or is it not possible?

Comment: so which `<a>` u need to change ?

Comment: u can use like `$("[href='/quote/1312678/cta_request.php']")`

Comment: @KishoreSahas I keep forgetting about that selector. Thanks for the yearly reminder.

Comment: you may use `$("#vdp_buttons [href='/appraisal/1312678/cta_request.php']").attr("href","newlink")` to change the link..

Comment: need to change the appraisal one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all your link tags and change the href when some condition holds as follows.

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ( href == '/old/link') { 
        $(this).attr('href', 'this/is/new/link')
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need use the select using `href` attribute, see below.

```
$("#vdp_buttons [href='/appraisal/1312678/cta_request.php']").attr("href","newlink")
```

DEMO :

```js
$("#vdp_buttons [href='/appraisal/1312678/cta_request.php']").attr("href","newlink");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-12  no_padding" id="vdp_buttons">
    <a href="/quote/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-2">
    Request Something     
    </a><br>
    <a href="/test_drive/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-2">
    Test Something   
    </a><br>
    <a href="/availability/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    Check Something 
    </a><br>
    <a href="/appraisal/1312678/cta_request.php" class="btn btn-success cta vdp-cta col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    Trade Something 
    </a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery to loop through all anchors:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
   $('a').each(function (i, v) {
      alert(this.href); 
   });
});
```

Put this in your  tag and you will see each href. Change via

```
this.href = "http://www.google.com"
```